# VBA Code to run when columns are changed

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have managed to work out some code to apply autofilters across 20 or so tables in a separate worksheet. the below code is running in the module for my main data sheet.
currently the code runs when any cell in my data sheet is changed. i want to modify the below code so that only it will only run when data in specific columns changes. for example column A , G AND M

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'this part runs the autofilter on my active sheet
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
'this part runs all the table autofilters in the sheet "template"
    Dim oList As ListObject
    For Each oList In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TEMPLATE").ListObjects
      oList.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
   Next oList
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to modify the below code so that only it will only run when data in specific columns changes. ... for example column A, G and M

You cannot. You must check does the range altered overlaps the range in interest, and perform the action only when this is true:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A,G:G,M:M")) Is Nothing Then
    'this part runs the autofilter on my active sheet
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
    'this part runs all the table autofilters in the sheet "template"
        Dim oList As ListObject
        For Each oList In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TEMPLATE").ListObjects
            oList.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
        Next oList
Else
    ' perform an action if the columns in interest are not altered (if needed)
    ' if not needed then Else section can be removed
End If
End Sub
```

Of course you may use any needed expression of `Range` datatype (Range, Columns, Rows, Cells, ...) instead of `Range("A:A,G:G,M:M")`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this helped a lot.